# consecutive date in a month

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

I have a data like this

```
Month   CalendarDate
1   02/01/2014 00:00
1   03/01/2014 00:00
1   04/01/2014 00:00
1   05/01/2014 00:00
1   06/01/2014 00:00
1   07/01/2014 00:00
1   08/01/2014 00:00
1   15/01/2014 00:00
1   16/01/2014 00:00
1   17/01/2014 00:00
1   18/01/2014 00:00
1   26/01/2014 00:00
1   27/01/2014 00:00
1   28/01/2014 00:00
1   29/01/2014 00:00
2   04/02/2014 00:00
2   05/02/2014 00:00
2   06/02/2014 00:00
2   07/02/2014 00:00
2   08/02/2014 00:00
2   09/02/2014 00:00
2   10/02/2014 00:00
```

Needs to find group of dates that are consecutive dates in a month for instance in jan month three groups that is 2 to 8, 15 to 18 and 26 to 29 
where as in feb month have only one group from 04 to 10

Comment: So, you want your output to be Jan-2014: 3 Feb-2014: 1? Is there a minimum number of consecutive dates (e.g. at least 3 dates) for the group to be counted?

Comment: yes you are correct. If no consecutive dates available in a month then 0

Answer (score 0):

I built the schema below, and added a couple of dates to ensure I got the edge cases. This will change the results to add one more grouping to each month:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTS (CalendarDate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/02/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/03/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/04/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/05/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/06/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/07/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/08/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/15/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/16/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/17/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/18/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/26/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/27/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/28/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/29/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('01/31/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('02/01/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('02/04/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('02/05/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('02/06/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('02/07/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('02/08/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('02/09/2014 00:00');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('02/10/2014 00:00');
```

Then I approached it from a variable stance, to make the subselect in the second query much shorter, and in the real world, reduce the number of scans on the real, larger table.

```
DECLARE @DateGroup TABLE (CalendarDate DATE, GroupID VARCHAR(40));
INSERT INTO @DateGroup
    SELECT CalendarDate
        , CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EVENTS E2 WHERE MONTH(E2.CalendarDate) = MONTH(E.CalendarDate) AND DATEDIFF(dd,E.CalendarDate,E2.CalendarDate) = -1) THEN 'Group'
            ELSE CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(40))
        END AS GroupID
    FROM EVENTS E

SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CalendarDate,113),8) AS MonthOfDate, COUNT(DISTINCT GroupID) AS Groups
FROM (
    SELECT CalendarDate, CASE GroupID WHEN 'Group' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 GroupID FROM @DateGroup E WHERE E.CalendarDate < D.CalendarDate AND GroupID != 'Group' ORDER BY CalendarDate DESC) ELSE GroupID END AS GroupID
    FROM @DateGroup D
    ) Z
GROUP BY RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CalendarDate,113),8)
ORDER BY MIN(CalendarDate)
```

This gave me the following results:

```
MonthOfDate Groups
Jan 2014    4
Feb 2014    2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte(Month, Year, Sequence) as
(
    select d.Month, 
    datepart(yy,d.CalendarDate),
    DATEPART(d, d.CalendarDate) - row_number() over(partition by Month order by Month, CalendarDate) Sequence
    from Dates d 
    group by d.Month, d.CalendarDate    
)

select Month, Year, COUNT(Sequence) Groups
from(
  select c.Month, c.Year,  COUNT(sequence) Sequence
  from cte c
  group by c.Month, c.Year, c.Sequence
  having COUNT(Sequence) > 2
) x
group by Month, Year
```

This line computes a value that will be repeated for each record in a sequential run

```
DATEPART(d, d.CalendarDate) - row_number() over(partition by Month order by Month, CalendarDate)
```

Then it's just a matter of grouping the results.  This query considers three consecutive months to be a group.  If you want to make it two consecutive months, then change this line

```
having COUNT(Sequence) > 2
```

to

```
having COUNT(Sequence) > 1
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bcdac/2)